# Configure Apache so that a subfolder is not processed by WSGI but by Apache itself

Tags: python, apache, flask, wsgi

I have configured WSGI in Apache as follows:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess a_name threads=10
WSGIPassAuthorization On
WSGIScriptAlias / path_to_wsgi_script
```

and it's working great. Every single request to / and "child-urls" (e.g. /data, /data1/data2, etc.) are being processed by the Python script.

I want to create a folder within / called /test and put normal files there (HTML, CSS, JS). Naturally I would like to access the files through URLs such as

```
http://whatever_domain/test/file1.html
```

Unfortunately, this is not working as, as I mentioned above, the Python script is being executed instead.

Is it possible to configure Apache so that a folder /test under / is not processed by WSGI but by Apache itself?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put an `Alias` directive for your desired directory above the WSGIScriptAlias:

```
Alias /test/ /path/to/test/directory/
WSGIScriptAlias / path_to_wsgi_script
```

For more information see the documentation.

- [Hosting of Static Files](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationGuidelines#Hosting_Of_Static_Files)